# Table converted from myISAM to INNODB is slowing down a query

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb, myisam

I have a table that was converted from myISAM to INNODB that is slowing down a query. This is a big table with lot of indexes.  MyIsam (on mysql5.6) returns result instantly, INNODB (on mysql5.7) takes 2 to 3 seconds. fnota is float. serieid and epnumber are int. Any idea why this is taking more time when doing index_merge?

Explain on MYISAM TABLE:

```
explain SELECT count( fnota ) , avg( fnota ) FROM myrates
          WHERE serieid =4376 AND epnumber ='149'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: myrates
         type: ref
possible_keys: serieid,epnumber,serieid_2
          key: serieid_2
      key_len: 8
          ref: const,const
         rows: 8207
        Extra: Using index condition
```

Explain on INNODB Table:

```
explain SELECT count( fnota ) , avg( fnota ) FROM myrates
          WHERE serieid =4376 AND epnumber ='149'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          id: 1
 select_type: SIMPLE
       table: myrates
  partitions: NULL
        type: index_merge
possible_keys: serieid,epnumber,serieid_2
         key: serieid,epnumber,serieid_2
     key_len: 4,4,8
         ref: NULL
        rows: 2
    filtered: 100.00
       Extra: Using intersect(serieid,epnumber,serieid_2); Using where
```

Indexes:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM myrates;
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| myrates |          0 | fbid      |            1 | userid      | A         |     1405506 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myrates |          0 | fbid      |            2 | serieid     | A         |     8617224 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myrates |          0 | fbid      |            3 | epnumber    | A         |   139638192 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myrates |          1 | serieid   |            1 | serieid     | A         |      257656 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myrates |          1 | epnumber  |            1 | epnumber    | A         |       93431 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myrates |          1 | serieid_2 |            1 | serieid     | A         |      186213 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myrates |          1 | serieid_2 |            2 | epnumber    | A         |     3309332 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myrates |          1 | userid    |            1 | userid      | A         |      866339 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myrates |          1 | userid    |            2 | serieid     | A         |     4656575 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE MYRATES; 
Table: myrates
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `myrates` (
  `userid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `serieid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `epnumber` float NOT NULL,
  `nota` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fnota` float NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `fbid` (`userid`,`serieid`,`epnumber`),
  KEY `serieid` (`serieid`),
  KEY `epnumber` (`epnumber`),
  KEY `serieid_2` (`serieid`,`epnumber`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`,`serieid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I would run `ANALYZE TABLE myrates` to make sure the index statistics are current. I agree this is odd, there's no reason for it to use an index merge if it's also using a compound index. I've never seen an EXPLAIN like that before.

Answer (score 1):

`DESCRIBE` does not precisely spell out the indexes you have.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It sounds like it is getting confused over your long list of overlapping indexes.

When you have a composite index such as `(serieid, epnumber)` you don't also need `(serieid)`.  Drop the latter index to 'fix' the problem.

It seems that key "userid" is redundant also, given that "fbid" starts with both of its two columns in the same order.

Comment: I edited the post and added. The reason I have these 2 "redundant" indexes serieid, and epnumber is because I have some queries where I look only for epnumbers. or only for serieid   . Do you think only the serieid_2 is enough?

Comment: @AlexPalombo - When you have `INDEX(a,b)`, you don't need `INDEX(a)`.  The former will handle any query that the latter handles.  In fact, I have seen one case where it the latter gets in the way of using the former.  That is, the Optimizer picked the shorter index even though the 2-column index was much better for the query.